# Saber quantas propriedades uma sessão do INI tem?

Tags: delphi, ini

Eu tenho um arquivo INI o qual uma sessão possui várias propriedades:

```
[DLLS]
Dll1=...
Dll2=...
Dll3=...
```

No exemplo acima existem 3 propriedades.

Existe algum método no *Delphi* para identificar quantas propriedades a sessão `[DLLS]` tem?

Answer (score 2):

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    var
      MeuINI : TIniFile;
      strValores : TStringList;
    begin   
      MeuINI := TIniFile.Create('Z:\Temp\Teste.ini');
      MeuINI.UpdateFile;
      strValores := TStringList.Create;

      if MeuINI.SectionExists('DLLS') then
        MeuINI.ReadSection('DLLS',strValores);

      ShowMessage(IntToStr(strValores.Count));
      ShowMessage(strValores.Text);   
    end;
```

Exemplo do clique de um botão que faz o que você quer:

- Mostra quantas chaves existem;
- Mostra o conteúdo delas;

Answer (score 1):

Pode ser feito da seguinte maneira, cria um novo projecto insira um `TButton` e um `TMemo` e no evento `onclick` do botão cole o seguinte código:

```
procedure TForm1.Btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var VCount: TStringList;
    INI: TiniFile;
begin
  VCount := TStringList.Create;

  INI := TIniFile.Create('c:\test.ini');
    if INI.SectionExists('DLLS') then INI.ReadSection('DLLS', VCount);
  INI.Free;

  memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(VCount.Count));
end;
```

Alguma dúvida coloque.